# How to send 1 Kafka message with a key?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am using this command: `bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server url --topic Notifications --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=:"`

I enter this command, and enter:

`1: {"producer": 4, "message": {"created_date": "2020-08-04 15:03:19.063196"}}`

Then it immediately expects a second line. But I only want to send 1 message, so I hit enter again, and get

`org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: No key found on line 2: q at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$LineMessageReader.readMessage(ConsoleProducer.scala:289) at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:51) at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)`

Comment: I would run the cli consumer at the same time in another terminal instance to see if the message is hitting the queue. The producer will display a new line input if the message sends successfully.

Comment: Hit Ctrl+C to exit console producer once you have sent the first message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the message is actually sent. `kafka-console-producer` accepts the input line by line. Every line (when you enter a newline character by hitting [Enter]) submits a message to the topic. After that `kafka-console-producer` continues to wait for the next input, should you send more messages. However, because for the next input you attempt to send an empty string, it doesn't parse indeed and the error is produced. This error, though, is for the second entry only. The first message should have been, normally, already sent by that time.

As @Patrick Kelly suggest in the comments, you may confirm this assumption by running a consumer on the topic in question and see what's in there. For example, run the `kafka-console-consumer` whilst entering the messages in the `kafka-console-producer` prompt.